# How to add script and css references on demand for a Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

**Context**

I've created a Blazor Server App using the Visual Studio 2019 template.
I will have different pages, and those pages may require different script and css references in the html `<head>` element.

**Question**

Instead of add all in advance in _Hosts.cshtml, how can I add some of them "on demand" when a particular .razor page is rendering (which requires that script...)?

Answer (score 1):

In the OnAfterRenderAsync event of that component, call js interop that will look for the specific link or script tags you need and add them to the DOM if they are missing. Depending on how your code and assets are structured, you may have to hardcode the entire js string in your component, unless you can have the needed function in a js file that is always loaded